# GNU Parallel - redirect output to a file with a specific name

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

In bash I am running GnuPG to decrypt some files and I would like the output to be redirected to a file having the same name, but a different extension. Basically, if my file is named

```
file1.sc.xz.gpg
```

the file which comes out after running the GnuPG tool I would like to be stored inside another file called

```
file1.sc.xz
```

I am currently trying

```
find . -type f | parallel "gpg {} > {}.sc.xz"
```

but this results in a file called file1.sc.xz.gpg.sc.xz. How can I do this?

Later edit: I would like to do this inside one single bash command, without knowing the filename in advance.

Comment: If `parallel` is an essential part of your question, consider mentioning it in the title. It's not part of bash, and a surprisingly complex tool.

Comment: (that said -- would an answer using `xargs -P` to work in parallel *without* GNU parallel be welcome?)

Answer (score 6):

You can use bash variable expansion to chop off the extension:

```
$ f=file1.sc.xz.gpg
$ echo ${f%.*}
file1.sc.xz
```

E.g.:

```
find . -type f | parallel bash -c 'f="{}"; g="${f%.*}"; gpg "$f" > "$g"'
```

---

Alternatively, use expansion of [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

```
find . -type f | parallel 'gpg "{}" > "{.}"'
```

Comment: BTW, the answers using `find` and `parallel` here won't work safely with all possible filenames. Consider names with literal newlines for a particular interesting corner case.

Comment: ...though given the lack of proper quoting, the current implementations are buggy even with files with simple whitespace in their names.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I recently accidentally copied a folder with a trailing space on my Android phone. Could not move files from it or remove the directory from the phone itself.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, ...if you want some guidance on dealing with those cases correctly, I'd be happy to help. Actually working on an answer demonstrating NUL-delimited streams of names right now.

Comment: Use `-print0` and `parallel --null` to safe-guard against hostile file names

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I defer that to classic http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, ...I actually disagree rather strongly with David there. Filenames with arbitrary content aren't broken; code that con't handle them correctly is broken.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What about filenames with backspaces?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, ...what about them?

Comment: Anyhow, we don't live in a world where the set of valid names has been restricted, even if that world would be a sensible or ideal one. Buffer overflows dumping junk into filenames *happens*; malicious users injecting content through filenames *happens*; and well-written code should handle all those cases.

Comment: (One of my former employers lost several TB of records used for accounting purposes on account of a buffer overflow throwing junk into a filename and a shell script that didn't quote correctly doing cleanup; it wasn't pretty).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In ideal world, that is true. In a real world handling all possible characters in filenames may be economically unreasonable: the client may not wish to pay for an extra day of work to handle funny characters.

Comment: The engineering time that former employer spent cleaning up after the mess I mention in the comment above far exceeded what prevention would have run.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: When trying to run find . -type f | parallel bash -c 'f="{}"; g="${f%.*}"; gpg "$f" > "$g"' I get /usr/local/bin/bash: : No such file or directory

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I cannot get any output file if I run this: find . -type f | parallel bash -c 'f="{}"; g="${f%.*}"; gpg "$f" > "$g"' Which is the extra stuff?

Comment: Insert `echo` in front of `gpg` to see what it is trying to invoke.

Comment: Also, substituting names into code here, you have a security risk if any filename contains, say, the literal string `$(rm -rf .)`. Much safer to keep data and code separately, pulling arguments off the command line in your script rather than substituting into it.

Answer (score 3):

If file names are guaranteed not to contain \n:

```
find . -type f | parallel gpg {} '>' {.}
parallel gpg {} '>' {.} ::: *
```

If file names may contain \n:

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 gpg {} '>' {.}
parallel -0 gpg {} '>' {.} ::: *
```

Note that opposite shell variables GNU Parallel's substitution strings should not be quoted. This will *not* create the file 12", but instead 12\" (which is wrong):

```
parallel "touch '{}'" ::: '12"'
```

These will all do the right thing:

```
parallel touch '{}' ::: '12"'
parallel "touch {}" ::: '12"'
parallel touch {} ::: '12"'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
  xargs -P 0 -n 1 -0 \
    bash -s -c 'for f; do g=${f%.*}; gpg "$f" >"$g"; done' _
```

Right now this processes only one file per shell, but you could trivially modify that by changing the `-n` value.

Comment: Don't you need double quotes around `${f%.*}`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, no; string-splitting and glob expansion don't happen on scalar assignments.